# how to achieve server-side less theme?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, less

I need to change the theme from server-side like this:

```
useEffect(()=>{
  const themeFromServer = {
    primaryColor:'d02a02'
  }
  //refresh .less file but not refresh page(if possible)
},[])

//then, refresh .less file
```

.less file

```
@primaryColor: #000000;

.header {
  color: @primaryColor;
}
```

but I don't know how to refresh the less file and change the variable in less file. or is there a way to use a javascript variable in .less file like this:

```
@import client from './somewhere'

function getPrimaryColor = (client) =>{
    switch (client) {
        case 'A':
    return 'red'
            break;
        case 'B':
    return 'blue'
            break;
    }
    default:
    return 'black'
}

@primaryColor:getPrimaryColor();


.header {
  color: @primaryColor;
}
```

Comment: The question is unclear for me. You have a LESS file on the server. Is it converted to CSS on the server or on the client? How does it change? Does the client know about the change?

Comment: @jabaa the LESS file is in clietn-side. I'm wondering if there is a way to dynamic change the LESS variable from jsx file?(like triggered by click button)

Comment: The server sends a LESS file to the client and the client converts it. Now you want to change the LESS file on the server and send the new file to the client, right? Is this a dev system or a production system? It's unusual that the client converts the LESS file. Usually you have a build step converting LESS files to CSS files and in production you just provide the CSS files.

Comment: @jabaa I got a online demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-twpmxg?file=src/App.js
the less file is in front-end project. and I need get theme data from server, to change the 
 less variable. the less file is not in server-side. but the theme configuration is from server.